# Minimal Deployment target available for new publishings in the App Store

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store, deployment-target

In this [link](https://developer.apple.com/news/?id=09122018c), we can find a statement from Apple stating the following:

> You can now submit apps that take advantage of the powerful new capabilities in the next release of iOS, watchOS, and tvOS. Build your apps using Xcode 10 GM seed, test with the latest releases of iOS 12, watchOS 5, and tvOS 12, and submit them for review.
>   Starting March 2019, all new apps and app updates for iPhone, including universal apps, will need to be built with the iOS 12 SDK and support iPhone XS Max. All new apps and app updates for Apple Watch will need to be built with the watchOS 5 SDK and support Apple Watch Series 4.

I understand that now I have to update Xcode to 10.2, and that's ok. But what is unclear for me - what is minimal deployment target available for new publishings? Right now I have an app which has a deployment target of iOS 9.0. Do I fit into the latest requirements of Apple and should I be worried about my deployment target at all?

During my searches in the internet I found that some people propose to have a deployment target which is `"latest-ios-version - 2.0 = deployment-target"`, but I don't know if that statement is legit.

Any insight would be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Yes**, you can still publish an application with a deployment target of iOS >8.0. All that matters is whether your app is built with the iOS 12 SDK (basically, if you're building with Xcode 10, it's a given).

Comment: Hello and thank you for your response! And additional thank you for your edit of my question (I feel a bit embarrassed :) )

Comment: You welcome and you don't need to feel embarrassed at all! Have fun using Stack Overflow!

Answer (score 0):

Starting April 26, 2021, all iOS and iPadOS apps submitted to the App Store must be built with Xcode 12 and the iOS 14 SDK. Refer https://developer.apple.com/ios/submit for more details.